# Firestore batch insert 375 documents per commit, but not 500 documents. Why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm tryng insert a little more them 1400 objects inside my firestore database by cloud function (with 540 seconds of timeout) using this code:

```js
...

const response = await fetch(url)
if (response.ok) {
    const json = await response.json()
    if (json.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
        const teams = json[`data`]
        
        var players = teams.flatMap((team) => {
            return team.squad.data
        })
        
        var playersBatch = []
        while (players.length > 0) {
            const playerBatch = players.splice(0, 375)
            playersBatch.push(playerBatch)
        }

        for (playerBatch of playersBatch) {
            const batch = database.batch()

            for (player of playerBatch) {
                const reference = database
                    .collection(`players`)
                    .doc(`${player.player_id}`)

                batch.set(reference, player, { merge: true })
            }

            await batch.commit()
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else {
    ...
}

...
```

The above code work for me, but work when I insert 375 documents per batch, when I try to insert 500 documents the batch commit not work in first loop and give me a timeout exception.

> Function execution took 540005 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Can batch produces timeout? Has batch any limitation when inserting huge documents? Why I can insert 375 but not 500 each time?

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: It's not the batch that is timing out but it requires more than 9 minutes to be completed, however your function is timing out after 9 minutes, which is it's upper limit for timeouts and this is why you get this error.

The problem in this case is the cloud function itself, not the batched write.

As you can see in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes):

> A batched write can contain up to 500 operations

However, the cloud functions [documentation for timeout](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout) says the following:

> Function execution time is limited by the timeout duration, which you can specify at function deployment time. By default, a function times out after 1 minute, but you can extend this period up to 9 minutes.

If you convert the `540005 ms` you will get roughly 9 minutes, which is the upper limit of Cloud Functions execution before timeout. So this is why you can't operate a 500 records batch but you can with 375 records, as it is under the 9 minutes timeout limit of the Cloud Function.

Comment: I'd argue it's because the `await batch.commit()` is inside the for loop (meaning that it is trying to write 375 docs, wait, write the next 375 docs, wait, repeat) where you could be using `await Promise.all(batches.map((b) => b.commit()))` instead outside of the loop to run all of these at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you are doing correctly, these are the steps you are trying to perform:

1. Fetch the URL
2. For each team in the response, extract a list of all players
3. For each player, update their data in the database

Slightly shuffling your code around and moving `await batch.commit()` out of the for loop (which made your code wait for each batch to complete before moving to the next), gives:

```
const response = await fetch(url)

if (!response.ok || response.status === 204) {
  // A 204 code will break response.json() with a parsing error
  // You might want to check for the 429 status here
  throw new Error(`Unexpected status code ${response.status}!`)
}

const json = await response.json() // note: empty bodies will throw a parsing error

if (!json.hasOwnProperty("data")) {
  throw new Error(`Unexpected response body!`, json)
}

const teams = json["data"]

const players = teams.flatMap((team) => {
    return team.squad.data // the array of players in this team
})

const playersInBatches = [];
while (players.length > 0) {
    const thisPlayerBatch = players.splice(0, 500)
    playersInBatches.push(thisPlayerBatch)
}

const batches = playersInBatches.map((playersInThisBatch) => {
    const dbBatch = database.batch()

    for (let player of playersInThisBatch) {
        const reference = database
            .collection("players")
            .doc(`${player.player_id}`)

        dbBatch.set(reference, player, { merge: true })
    }

    return dbBatch
}

// commit all batches in parallel and wait for them to finish
await Promise.all(batches.map((b) => b.commit())) 

console.log("Synced successfully!")
```

Notes:

- As an expansion to what you are doing, you may want to store the response's caching headers like the `ETag` or `Last-Modified`. This allows you to ask the third-party server if the data has changed at all before downloading it.
- I've replaced your `if (condition) { /* do lots of work */ } else { /* do small amount of work to handle error */ }` with `if (!condition) { /* do small amount of work to handle error */ return; } /* do lots of work */`. This is known as "failing-fast" and is used to prevent large and/or nested `if-else` trees while also showing your error handling next to what's causing the error.
- If any one batch fails, then the others may not be successfully written to the database, but this bug is in your original code too. You could change the last lines to the following to make them not kill the other batches:

```
// commit all batches in parallel and wait for them to finish
const results = await Promise.all(batches.map(
    (b) => b.commit().then(
        () => ({success: true}),
        (error) => ({success: false, error})
    )
))

let succeeded = 0, failed = 0

results.forEach(result => result.success ? succeeded++ : failed++)

if (failed > 0) {
    console.log(`Synced ${succeeded}/${results.length} batches of players successfully!`)
    return
}

console.log("Synced all players successfully!")
```

---

You also aren't the first to encounter this problem of batching your writes to your database. It's common enough that there is this [`MultiBatch`](https://gist.github.com/samthecodingman/faba163b31488ab885bacefa7f63d121) utility class that handles the batches for you.

```
const response = await fetch(url)

if (!response.ok || response.status === 204) {
  // A 204 code will break response.json() with a parsing error
  // You might want to check for the 429 status here
  throw new Error(`Unexpected status code ${response.status}!`)
}

const json = await response.json() // note: empty bodies will throw a parsing error

if (!json.hasOwnProperty("data")) {
  throw new Error(`Unexpected response body!`, json)
}

const teams = json["data"]
const multiBatch = new MultiBatch(database)
const playersColRef = database.collection("players")

teams.forEach((team) => {
     team.squad.data // the array of players in this team
         .forEach(player => {
             const reference = playersColRef.doc(`${player.player_id}`)
             multiBatch.set(reference, player, { merge: true })
         })
})

await multiBatch.commit(/* pass true here to suppress errors */)

console.log("Synced successfully!")
```